# Getting a NullPointerException on a String comparison

Tags: android

I get a null value from doseTimeString when I output with:

```
   Log.d("dosetimeString", "" + dosetimeString);
```

But if I use an if condition on this line, it gives me a NullPointerException:

```
if (dosetimeString.equals("null") || dosetimeString == null
    || dosetimeString.equals(""))  {
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The NullPointerException is occurring on this bit of your if statement:

```
dosetimeString.equals("null")
```

because you are calling a method on a null object, and as Roflcoptr says, if you actually need all those tests, you should make that line read:

```
if (dosetimeString == null || dosetimeString.equals("null") || dosetimeString.equals("")) {
```

However, if you just want to check if it is null, you only need the first condition.

```
if (dosetimeString == null) {
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because first you test

```
dosetimeString.equals("null")
```

There you try to access variable dosetimeString which is null.

So just use:

```
dosetimeString == null
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because doestimeString is null. You can't access member functions on a null object!

Put the doestiemString==null before doestimeString.equals( "null" ) and you should be ok.

```
if (dosetimeString == null || dosetimeString.equals("null") || dosetimeString.equals("")){

}
```